# Entities Framework пробелма с подключением к базе

Tags: entity-framework, vb.net

Имеется два проекта.
Первый проект является `.dll` библиотекой, в котором вложено подключение `Entities Framework` и заложена логика фукнционала, `GridView`.

Второй же проект, является главным проектом и по нажатии на кнопку, показывает `GUI` и функционал, расположенный в этом `.dll`

Если запускать первый отдельно от второго, как обычное `WinForm` приложение, все работает и показывает. Когда же подключаю первое приложение ко второму, при получении данных с DB показывает что не найден "`MyEntities`" в конфигурации, хотя он там есть.

Так выглядит мой App.config во втором проекте. Проект также указан как стартовой. Копаюсь уже второй день и перерыл много статей, но не могу найти решение этой проблемы.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System">
      <section name="DevExpress.LookAndFeel.Design.AppSettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <DevExpress.LookAndFeel.Design.AppSettings>
      <setting name="DefaultAppSkin" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Skin/The Bezier</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultPalette" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Gloom Gloom</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="TouchUI" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="TouchScaleFactor" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DirectX" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="RegisterUserSkins" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FontBehavior" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultAppFont" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DPIAwarenessMode" serializeAs="String">
        <value>System</value>
      </setting>
    </DevExpress.LookAndFeel.Design.AppSettings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <!-- Dieser Abschnitt definiert die Protokollierungskonfiguration für My.Application.Log -->
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="FileLog"/>
          <!-- Auskommentierung des nachfolgenden Abschnitts aufheben, um in das Anwendungsereignisprotokoll zu schreiben -->
          <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
      <!-- Auskommentierung des nachfolgenden Abschnitts aufheben und APPLICATION_NAME durch den Namen der Anwendung ersetzen, um in das Anwendungsereignisprotokoll zu schreiben -->
      <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory >
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBA_Terminliste.csdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.ssdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=atx-srv-58;initial catalog=ATX_PLSNG;persist security info=True;user id=Some_User;password=Some_PW;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавив мой String соединения в `.Context.vb`

```
Partial Public Class ATX_PLSNGEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
      MyBase.New("metadata=res://*/DBA_Terminliste.csdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.ssdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=SomeServer;initial catalog=ATX_PLSNG;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomePW;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
      Throw New UnintentionalCodeFirstException()
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Property Terminliste() As DbSet(Of Terminliste)

  End Class
```